# Date filter for not showing the recent date data in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I am building a dashboard for retention. The data that I am getting for the most recent day seems to have huge spikes because the denominator is not having entire data for the day.

So, I just want to show the data till previous day and it should be automated likewise.

Please let me know if anyone had dealt with the same problem.

Thanks,
Sai

Comment: So you want to see everything except for today's data, right?

Comment: Hey Sam, So I want the data till (10/24th)  i.e. yesterday and tomorrow(10/26th) the dashboard should refresh and I should be able to see data till (10/25). How can I do that?

Comment: Yes sam, I want to see everything except today's data.

Comment: Hi Kriz, I have had this exact same issue. See my answer below :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this is through creating a calculated field:
Create a field called Recent Date as follows:

```
DATETRUNC('day',[Date]) = {FIXED : MAX(DATETRUNC('day',[Date]))}
```

What this does is creates a Boolean field where the most recent date will be flagged as TRUE and all others as FALSE.

Drag this field into the filters pane and select FALSE. This will remove the most recent dates data.

Answer (score 0):

Create a calculated field to return a boolean value if the data is from today's date. Then filter on False.

```
DATETRUNC('day', [Your Date Field]) = DATETRUNC('day', TODAY())
```